# Is there a way to lock the Google Translate app to a specific Japanese character set (camera translate)?

Tags: google-translate

I'm using my phone to translate menus etc in a Japanese videogame (PS4/5), and it tells me like 12 different things it could be. It's ridiculous. Isn't there a specific Japanese character set games use? Can I lock the app to that???

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Chinese which has traditional and simplified character sets, **there is only 1 Japanese character set.**

However, looks like the translation quality is more unreliable in "Instant" mode. Some possible causes:

- The quality/size of the image, which may affect the optical character recognition (OCR, or simply image-to-text). Blurry/small text will be harder to interpret, and any background near the text may also obstruct the clarity.
- The Japanese word itself, since without more context, some words can have many interpretations, or...
- The algorithm sacrifices quality for speed. In "Instant" mode, the app tries to translate as quickly as possible and will continuously retranslate the image, even for a static image.

For more reliable translation, *it is better to use the "Scan" mode instead of the "Instant" mode* since it also provides the original text so that the user can cross-check with other dictionaries/translation tools.

Comment: Scan sucks. Instant mode is still working better in spite of being annoying. I sit 2ft from a 55" 4K screen and put my elbow on my desk to stabilize the phone. Plus these phones have like 12000 megapixel lenses now. This should work better. Was just hoping to improve it before the new game releases on Wednesday.

Comment: @MentallyIrregular then perhaps Google Translate is not the most suitable app for your case, though I don't know any alternatives. You might want to ask for a better live translation app on [softwarerecs.se] then.